# how to split column with condition

Tags: python, database, python-3.x, pandas, split

so, I would like to know how I can divide a column with conditions. My idea is to study the activity of the user, but for this I need to put a condition.
I have the dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'User': ["juan","juan","juan","juan","petter","petter","petter","petter","petter","petter","petter","petter","ana","ana","ana","ana","raul","raul","raul","raul"],
               'time': ["2/1/2019","3/1/2019","4/1/2019","6/1/2019","2/1/2019","5/1/2019","6/1/2019","10/1/2019","11/1/2019","12/1/2019","13/1/2019","14/1/2019","8/1/2019","10/1/2019","15/1/2019","20/1/2019","15/1/2019","17/1/2019","18/1/2019","19/1/2019"],
                'activity': ["fly", "hotel","car","jump","fly", "hotel","jump","car","fly", "car","hotel","car","car", "hotl","car","hotel","fly", "hotel","car","car"],
              '%timeper_user': ["4 days","4 days","4 days","4 days","8 days","8 days","8 days","8 days","3 days","3 days","3 days","3 days","12 days","12 days","12 days","12 days","4 days","4 days","4 days","4 days"]})
```

as you will see, each user has a column (time), and another column(%timeper_user)per user. then a column (activity), which is the activity that each user performs during a period of time. The idea is make a "conditional split" that with each activity in a different column. Act1,Act2,Act3,Act3. But when the user performs an activity outside of time (time +% timeper_user), place the activities in different columns such as: Act21, Act 22, Act 23, Act24 I would like it to be like this:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'User': ["juan","petter","ana","raul"],
              "act1":["fly","fly","car","fly"],
              "act2":["hotel","hotel","hotel","hotel"],
              "act3":["car","jump","car","car"],
              "act4":["jump","car","hotel","car"],
              "actn":["","","",""],
              "act21":["","fly","",""],
              "act22":["","car","",""],
              "act23":["","hotel","",""],
              "act24":["","car","",""]})
```

(DF2) is the output that what I want
See the user Petter exceeded the time (2/1/2019 + 8 days) = 10/1/2019. So from 11/1/2019 the activities are placed in Act21, Act22, Act23, Act24.
I have many users, so I do not know how to do a function that performs this and takes all (user by user). if you could help me, I would appreciate it very much. Thank you

Comment: Welcome to SO, could you please post sample expected output in your post too.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 sorry if I have not explained well. But I published it, DF is the data that I have. and the second case (DF2) is the output that what I want

Comment: Is it correct, that activity should appear in Act21, Act22, etc if it meets both of these conditions: 1) given user performed this activity in the past 2) `time` of repeated activity is greater that `time` of previous activity + `timeper_user` of previous activity?

Comment: @AlexeyMilogradov yes

Answer (score 0):

The idea is . if a user make a event between the range (time +% time per user) it means that all the activities belong inside enter the activity range 1 (act1, Act12, Act13, Act 14). if the date is greater, it means that the user would enter activity2 (act21, act22, act23, act24). In simple words ... if petter goes from USA to Madrid, he may go to a hotel, rent a car, and try a flight. but around there when he returns to the USA, Petter maybe buys a second flight (which would enter into range activity 2 (act 21, act22, Act23, act24) . If you run the df... Is the dataframe that I have .. and df2 is the data that I want to make